# assigning result of GetDayOfYear() to a string variable

Tags: c#, string, datetime, calendar

My program has to read date and convert to Julianday and resultant day should be a string which can be used further. I am not able to convert day returned from `GetDayOfYear` method to a variable. Here is the sample of the code. Please suggest how to achieve this.

```
DateTime myDT = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, new JulianCalendar());
JulianCalendar mycal = new JulianCalendar();
Console.WriteLine("   DayOfYear:    {0}", mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT));
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

But not able to assign it to a string variable.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar.getdayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx, will return `int`, you just need `ToString()` not necessary to specify format in it

Comment: Why do you need to store the `int` as `string` to be able to use it further? Store it as the most appropriate type which is `int`  and convert it to a string when you want to display it, not earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to use:

```
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString();
```

You dont need to overload the `ToString` method as

[GetDayOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar.getdayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the day of the year in the specified DateTime.

Comment: True. But OP can store it as the correct type which is `int`. No need to convert it to `string` to be able to "use it further"

Comment: @TimSchmelter:- Agreed, but since the intent of OP is not clear, I provided it. Storing it as int and then converting to string when required is an ideal way.

Answer (score 0):

The function GetDayOfYear gets you the ordinal of the day in the calendar, for example Jan 1 returns you 1.

The function returns an integer so if you want to convert it to a string the code is this

```
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString();
```

instead of

```
String dateInString = mycal.GetDayOfYear(myDT).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

You can take a look at the MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)